# php arrays and array mapping based on text

Tags: php, arrays

I get different text strings for orders based on a shipping method. For example an order could return any of the following:

```
productmatrix_Pick-up_at_Store
productmatrix_Standard
productmatrix_3-Day_Delivery
productmatrix_Pick-up_at_Store_-_Rush_Processing
productmatrix_2-Day_Delivery
productmatrix_1-Day_Delivery_-_Rush_Processing
```

I also have a "map" of production codes I need to tie these into.  The key is the text to match on.  The value is what I need.  The map looks like this:

```
$shipToProductionMap = array(
    "1-day" => 'D',
    "2-day" => 'E',
    "3-day" => 'C',
    "standard" => 'Normal',
    "pick-up" => 'P'
);
```

My goal is to create a function that will return the correct value from the `$shipToProductionMap` based on the string I pass to it.  Something like:

```
function getCorrectShipCode($text){
 if(strtolower($text) == if we find a hit in the map){
   return $valueFromMap;
 }
}
```

So for example, if I did this I would get `P` as the returned value:

```
$result = getCorrectShipCode('productmatrix_Pick-up_at_Store');
//$result = 'P';
```

How is the best way to do do this?

Comment: This seems like a very hacky way to approach the problem. Do you not have control over how order information is sent for processing?  Why pass around strings as opposed to objects or arrays that call tell you precisely what you need to know with some string comparison workaround?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `foreach` and [stripos](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.stripos.php) to match the scenario.

```
echo getCorrectShipCode('productmatrix_2-Day_Delivery');

function getCorrectShipCode($text){

    $shipToProductionMap = array(
                  "1-day" => 'D',
                  "2-day" => 'E',
                  "3-day" => 'C',
                  "standard" => 'Normal',
                   "pick-up" => 'P'
    );

    foreach($shipToProductionMap as $key => $value)
    {

        if(stripos($text, $key) !== false) 
        {

            return $value;

            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here is a working function called `getCorrectShipCode` which uses [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to compare the array key values in the ship to production map to compare against a string passed to it. I have it rolling through all of the values in a test array & all works as outlined:

```
// Set the strings in a test array.
$test_strings = array();
$test_strings[] = 'productmatrix_Pick-up_at_Store';
$test_strings[] = 'productmatrix_Standard';
$test_strings[] = 'productmatrix_3-Day_Delivery';
$test_strings[] = 'productmatrix_Pick-up_at_Store_-_Rush_Processing';
$test_strings[] = 'productmatrix_2-Day_Delivery';
$test_strings[] = 'productmatrix_1-Day_Delivery_-_Rush_Processing';

// Roll through all of the strings in the test array.
foreach ($test_strings as $test_string) {
  echo getCorrectShipCode($test_string) . '<br />';
}

// The actual 'getCorrectShipCode()' function.
function getCorrectShipCode($text) {

  // Set the ship to production map.
  $shipToProductionMap = array(
      "1-day" => 'D',
      "2-day" => 'E',
      "3-day" => 'C',
      "standard" => 'Normal',
      "pick-up" => 'P'
  );

  // Set the regex pattern based on the array keys in the ship to production map.
  $regex_pattern = '/(?:' . implode('|', array_keys($shipToProductionMap)) . ')/i';

  // Run a regex to get the value based on the array keys in the ship to production map.
  preg_match($regex_pattern, $text, $matches);

  // Set the result if there is a result.
  $ret = null;
  if (array_key_exists(strtolower($matches[0]), $shipToProductionMap)) {
    $ret = $shipToProductionMap[strtolower($matches[0])];
  }
  
  // Return a value.
  return $ret;

} // getCorrectShipCode
```